# compile project dependencies with latest version of android support library

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, repository, android-support-library

I was using `25` as `targetSdkVersion`,`compileSdkVersion` in my project. Then a warning showed up.

> Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details.

So I raised it to `26`. And I opened my `SDK Manager` and updated everything:

`SDK Tools , SDK Platform-Tools` , etc.

Then another warning showed up:

> This support library should not use a lower version (25) than the `targetSdkVersion` (26)

I was using this version:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Now I don't know to which version exactly should I change to.

I tried `7:26.0.0` which my `SDK Platform-Tools` version is now.

I tried `7:26.0.2` which my `SDK Tools` version is now.

Both of them give me error after sync:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.appcompat-v7:26.0.2
>
> Install repository and sync project

Then if I click on `Install` nothing will happen

Now I have a simple question. How can I find out what is the latest version of support library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Then another warning showed up:
>
> ```
> This support library should not use a lower version (25) than the targetSdkVersion (26)
> ```
>
> Now I don't know to wich version exactly should I change to.

Either one as you simply should have version match here, so either lower your `targetSdkVersion` to `25` or use **valid** version for 26+ libs.

> Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0 Install Repository and sync project

26 is not officially out yet so just RCs or betas, therefore valid version string is i.e. `26.0.0-beta1`.

Finally, you should check if your `repository` includes new google maven repo, otherwise some artefacts will not be available for your project incl. recent betas of support libs.

See [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven) for details of setting it all up.

Answer (score 27):

Add maven repository to your project gradle file:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio beta4 I had to add `google()` to the repositories in the projects `build.gradle` file. This seems to be an update from Celt K. B.'s answer.

This is what my `build.gradle` file looks like now.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

A trick is to create a new project and see what the settings are in the default `build.gradle` files.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Try this in your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
}
```